# Are the "snow," "snowball," and "snowfall" tags related to each other?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There are questions that are tagged [snow](/questions/tagged/snow), [snowball](/questions/tagged/snowball), [snowfall](/questions/tagged/snowfall).

Are these tags related, and one should replace the other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only related in the stem word.

- [snowball](/questions/tagged/snowball) - Small string handling programming language used for stemming
- [snowfall](/questions/tagged/snowfall) - R project package based around snow
- [snow](/questions/tagged/snow) - Often used when people want to specify [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard). You'll most likely find snow balled up the leopard tag. Sometimes used for the weather condition. Right now only two are showing as part of [the R project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snow+r).